# Passing a parameter within Linq

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0

I have the following code within a method:

```
someData = table.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(row => row.someRow.Equals("Something"))
    .Sum(row => row.AnotherRow);
```

On the last line I want to pass in a parameter from somewhere else which will replace .AnotherRow

In other words, something like:

```
.Sum(row => row. + myParameter);
```

Any ideas?  I get an error when I try the above.  Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot pass something that would represent `.AnotherRow`, but you can pass a functor that picks the desired attribute from your object.

Let's say `table` is `IEnumerable<MyClass>`. Then you can do this:

```
int SumSelected(Func<MyClass,int> attrSelector) {
    return table.AsEnumerable()
        .Where(row => row.someRow.Equals("Something"))
        .Sum(row => attrSelector(AnotherRow));
}
```

Now you can call this method with a "selector" that designates the attributes to be added up, as follows:

```
var totalCustomers = SumSelected(obj => obj.CustomerCount);
var totalStores = SumSelected(obj => obj.StoreCount);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think:

```
someData = table.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(row => row.someRow.Equals("Something"))
g.Sum(row => Calculate(row => row.AnotherRow, row1 =>row1.AnotherRow));
```

Method Calculate:

```
 private double Calculate(double d1, double d2)
    {
        return d1 + d2;
    }
```